# Call another php file

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest, apple-push-notifications

I'm building an iPhone push server, and trying to get the push to work. I have a message.php file which put new message in the database, and then add the message to a push_queue table in the database.

To send the push, I manually have to go to the browser and call the push file (../push/push.php) which will send out the push.

Is there any way I can call the push.php file from the message.php file automatically?

I tried `require_one`, `include`, `exec` and `file_get_contents` without any luck.

It works if I use:

```
header('Location: ../push/push.php');
```

However, the push.php file takes a couple of seconds to execute and finish, so there's a delay for the user when trying to send a message.

I guess I could use a cron job to call the push.php file, but I'd rather not.

Here is the core function in push.php (based on http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2):

```
function start()
{
    //writeToLog('Connecting to ' . $this->server);

    if (!$this->connectToAPNS())
        exit;


    while (true)
    {
        // Do at most 20 messages at a time. Note: we send each message in
        // a separate packet to APNS. It would be more efficient if we 
        // combined several messages into one packet, but this script isn't
        // smart enough to do that. ;-)

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM push_queue WHERE time_sent IS NULL LIMIT 20');
        $stmt->execute();
        $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $deletedIds = array();

        foreach ($messages as $message)
        {
            if ($this->sendNotification($message->message_id, $message->device_token, $message->payload))
            {
                //$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE push_queue SET time_sent = NOW() WHERE message_id = ?');
                //$stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

                 $deletedIds[] = $message->message_id;

                //$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id = ?');
                //$stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

            }
            else  // failed to deliver
            {
                $this->reconnectToAPNS();
            }
        }

        //Delete the chunk of messages.
        $this->pdo->query('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id IN ('.implode(',', $deletedIds).')');

        unset($messages);           
    }
}
```

Comment: How your push works? Is it Comet or your Iphone app calls server every x seconds to query for new messages?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. The app calls the server every x seconds to query..

Comment: Ok, so what does push.php? Some code example will be better.

Comment: I edited in the push.php send function above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function or class that does everything that your push.php does and call it when a new message is received or when the iPhone app queries for new messages. In this case you will not need to call other PHP in message.php.

This is a concept of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) i.e. having your business logic separated from your controllers. In this case pushing is a business logic and message.php and push.php are your controllers.